# How do you invite friends to the Halloween 2018 Google Doodle?

Tags: google-doodles

I have been playing [Halloween 2018 Doodle](https://www.google.com/doodles/halloween-2018) for a long time but I have not found a way to share a link with friends.  How can I invite them?

Answer (score 1):

After starting [the doodle](https://www.google.com/doodles/halloween-2018), there is a Host Game button in the bottom right:

[image: Host Game Button]

After you click this button, it will ask if you want to create a private match.  Click yes, and you will be prompted with a screen with a link you can give to your friends:

[image: Link]

On your friends end, it should look like this after they navigate to the link:

[image: Friend screen]

Notice how there are now two ghosts on the screen, and it says 2/8 players ready. When you are ready, the host presses the start game button and you and your friends should load in.  I tested this locally with two different tabs in Google Chrome and it seems to work.